# Groovy pattern or regular expression for finding a file path

Tags: regex, file, groovy, directory, find

I am trying to find one file path among many possible paths existing under some "basedir".

The sought file path has the following characteristics:

1. the path is under the known "basedir", e.g. under
   "C:\somedir\basedir\"
2. the path always contains one known subdirectory name, e.g. "SUBDIRNAMEWEKNOW"
3. the file name is also known, e.g. "filename.xml"

So, the sought file path might be e.g. :

```
C:\somedir\basedir\SUBDIRNAMEWEKNOW\someotherdir\filename.xml
C:\somedir\basedir\someotherdir\SUBDIRNAMEWEKNOW\someotherdir\filename.xml
```

or any other combination of any subdirectories under the known "basedir".

The best extent of my Groovy knowledge is concentrated in this piece of code:

```
def file_paths = new FileNameFinder().getFileNames(basedir, '**/filename.xml')
```

The output of this code looks like this:

```
C:\somedir\basedir\Test-Folder\filename.xml,
C:\somedir\basedir\Test-Folder\someotherdir\someotherdir\filename.xml, 
C:\somedir\basedir\someotherdir\SUBDIRNAMEWEKNOW\filename.xml
C:\somedir\basedir\someotherdir\filename.xml
```

And only one path is correct. The one with C:\somedir\basedir\someotherdir\SUBDIRNAMEWEKNOW\filename.xml

Alternative code with regexp would look like this:

```
def file_paths = FileNameByRegexFinder().getFileNames(basedir, /.filename.xml/)
```

Do you have an idea how I might use a pattern or a regular expression to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

FileNameFinder.getFileNames expects an [ANT pattern](https://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns) as the second argument.
In your case, the most relevant is `**` placeholder which matches zero or more directories. The pattern would be:

```
def file_paths = new FileNameFinder().getFileNames(basedir, '**/SUBDIRNAMEWEKNOW/**/filename.xml')
```